# Targeting an object property that changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I am creating a state capitals quiz and am verifying the selected quiz answer with the correct answer which is stored in an object.  I am having a tough time targeting the 'capital' property in the object because the quiz question is different every time.  I could do states.texas.capital but that would only target the capital of Texas.  I need something that would be similar to states.[current state in quiz].capital.  I am thinking I might need a variable to add in but I'm not sure how I would create it.  The issue is at the bottom of the script in the if statement condition. Thank you for any help.

```js
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'
];

var cities = {
    alabama: {
        image: 'state-images/alabama.jpg',
        capital: 'Montgomery',
        options: ['Tuscaloosa', 'Montgomery', 'Birmingham', 'Huntsville']
    },

    alaska: {
        image: 'state-images/alaska.jpg',
        capital: 'Juneau',
        options: ['Anchorage', 'Fairbanks', 'Juneau', 'Nome']
    },

    arizona: {
        image: 'state-images/arizona.jpg',
        capital: 'Phoenix',
        options: ['Tuscon', 'Scottsdale', 'Yuma', 'Phoenix']
    }
    }
    
    var currentState = states[Math.floor(Math.random() * states.length)];

function getState() {

    document.getElementById('activeState').innerHTML = currentState;

}

getState();

switch (currentState) {
    case 'Alabama':
        document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities.alabama.options[0];
        document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities.alabama.options[1];
        document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities.alabama.options[2];
        document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities.alabama.options[3];
        document.getElementById('stateImage').src = 'state-images/alabama.jpg';
        break;

    case 'Alaska':
        document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities.alaska.options[0];
        document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities.alaska.options[1];
        document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities.alaska.options[2];
        document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities.alaska.options[3];
        document.getElementById('stateImage').src = 'state-images/alaska.jpg';
        break;

    case 'Arizona':
        document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities.arizona.options[0];
        document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities.arizona.options[1];
        document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities.arizona.options[2];
        document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities.arizona.options[3];
        document.getElementById('stateImage').src = 'state-images/arizona.jpg';
        break;
}
    
    
    function answerCheck(clicked_id) {

    var clickedAnswer = document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML;

    if (clickedAnswer == cities.currentState.capital) {
        document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.background = "green"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.background = "red"; 
    }
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="question">
            <p>What is the Capital of</p>
            <p id='activeState'></p>
        </div>
        <div class="state-image">
            <img id='stateImage' src="State-images/alabama.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="options">
            <ul>
                <li id="firstOption">
                    <button class="choice" id="choice1" onclick="answerCheck(this.id)"></button>
                </li>
                <li id="secondOption">
                    <button class="choice" id="choice2" onclick="answerCheck(this.id)"></button>
                </li>
                <li id="thirdOption">
                    <button class="choice" id="choice3" onclick="answerCheck(this.id)"></button>
                </li>
                <li id="forthOption">
                    <button class="choice" id="choice4" onclick="answerCheck(this.id)"></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Do you mean somethi g like cities[0].options .. cities[1].options or you mean something easier?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (clickedAnswer == cities.currentState.capital) {
```

should be

```
if (clickedAnswer == cities[currentState].capital) {
```

but your property is lower case and the `currentState` is capitalized so it should instead be

```
if (clickedAnswer == cities[currentState.toLowerCase()].capital) {
```

because there is no `currentState` property in the object `cities` but instead you need the property name which is the value of `currentState`.

Ok since you have lot of duplicated code, I thought you would some help, so I took your code and refactored it like this, I also added some for styles.

```js
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'],
  cities, currentState;

cities = {
  alabama: {
    image: 'state-images/alabama.jpg',
    capital: 'Montgomery',
    options: ['Tuscaloosa', 'Montgomery', 'Birmingham', 'Huntsville']
  },
  alaska: {
    image: 'state-images/alaska.jpg',
    capital: 'Juneau',
    options: ['Anchorage', 'Fairbanks', 'Juneau', 'Nome']
  },
  arizona: {
    image: 'state-images/arizona.jpg',
    capital: 'Phoenix',
    options: ['Tuscon', 'Scottsdale', 'Yuma', 'Phoenix']
  }
}
    
currentState = states[Math.floor(Math.random() * states.length)];

function getState() {
  document.getElementById('activeState').innerHTML = currentState;
  document.querySelector(".options").innerHTML = `
    ${cities[currentState.toLowerCase()].options.map(function(opt) {
      return `<button class="choice">${opt}</button>`
    }).join("")}
  `;
}

getState();
    
document.querySelector(".options").onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.className !== "choice") {
    return;
  }
  if(e.target.textContent === cities[currentState.toLowerCase()].capital) {
    e.target.style.background = "green"; 
  }else {
    e.target.style.background = "red";
  }
};
```

```css
.choice {
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  font: bold 15px monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="question">
    <p>What is the Capital of <span id='activeState'></span>?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="state-image">
    <img id='stateImage' src="State-images/alabama.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="options"></div>
</div>
```

And now you can develop on top of my code if you want, happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  When I switch it to that I get a console message of "Cannot read property 'capital' of undefined."  Would you know why that is?

Comment: I didn't see that your `currentState` string is capitaliazed, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

On the line you randomly choose the city

```js
var currentState = states[Math.floor(Math.random() * states.length)];
```

you need to make sure the object you choose from `cities` array is also correct. I suggest putting your random number into variable every time, then picking correct values from your arrays (it is relying a lot on same order so I would rather suggest to refactor this code.

```js
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * states.length);
const currentState = states[random];
const currentCity = cities[random];
```

Last lines of code should then look like this:

```
if (clickedAnswer == currentCity.capital) {
        document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.background = "green"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.background = "red"; 
    }
```

This would be the solution with minimal changes to your code. But there is a lot of repetition and uncompatibility. Refactor it.